# ChartsJS bar chart with HH:MM:SS format

Tags: javascript, time, format, chart.js

I have a chartsJS as type: 'bar'. This works fine with data sets of numbers or string. How can I create a data set which consist of time format HH:MM:SS. My Chart so far looks like this:

```
    let hours = ["40", "20", "15", "10"];
    let frameworks = ['Week1', 'Week2', 'Week3'];

    let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: frameworks,
            datasets: [{
                data: hours,
            }],
        },
    });
```

I want the array "hours" to consist of

```
let hours = ["01:00:00", "02:00:00", "03:00:00", "04:00:00"];
```

How can I format this? Been looking around and not been able to come up with a soluiton just yet.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do it with `moment` library.

It's the best library for working with time and dates.

You can find here documentation: https://momentjs.com/